# Wrong JSON for Google API PHP client with service account

Tags: authentication, google-api, google-api-php-client, google-api-client

I'm trying to implement a connection from my laptop to Google API using the method of [OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/service-accounts). I'm working in PHP.

I've declared that account and downloaded the associated JSON file.

I've also read [this changelog](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/UPGRADING.md#google_auth_assertioncredentials-has-been-removed). The original documentation seems outdated as it uses the P12 strategy.

I've coded :

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '/home/samuel/workspace/DABphp/lib/Google/');
require_once 'autoload.php';
[...]
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig('private/DABmap-2.json');
$client->useDefaultApplicationCredentials();
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fusiontables');
if ($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion();
}
```

I'm getting this error :

> Uncaught exception 'Google_Exception' with message 'Invalid client secret JSON file.' in /home/samuel/workspace/DABphp/lib/Google/Client.php:171 Stack trace: #0 /home/samuel/workspace/DABphp/ajouter-dab.php(80): Google_Client->setAuthConfig('private/DABmap-...') #1 {main}

I've tried to download again a fresh key. I didn't touch the file. That's the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a known bug referenced [here](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/issues/455).